# Information on deleted users?

Tags: support

Is there any way of getting information on deleted users? [This deleted answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/898/130) was created by *user1413*, from context this appears to be *littleadv*. Is there some way I can find out more information on what happened? Did the user delete their own account, or was their account deleted by a moderator? Is this a community decision, or does a single diamond moderator do so single-handedly?

Answer (score 3):

You can safely assume that the user requested for their account to be removed, moderators (that we don't have yet) and SE employees wouldn't remove an account without the user asking for it, with the exception of obvious spam accounts.

I'm not so sure what more information you are looking for, but I'm afraid this is all that you'll get, there's absolutely no reason for specifics to be discussed publicly.

Comment: Specifics CAN be discussed publically since they happened under CC-whatever SE license in a public forum, and publicality was intended by the user. I have doubts that deleting posts like that from the UI is done to preserve their contents' privacy, though I could be wrong.

Comment: @DVK He did post a comment on Meta requesting his account to be deleted, that's hardly private. I'm not saying specifics can't be discussed publicly (you might be thinking of my [other answer](http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/a/250/101)), I'm saying there's absolutely no reason for it - i.e. nothing useful can come out of such a discussion.

Comment: I'm a scientist by training. "I'm curious" is a good enough justufication for asking a question for me, independent of my own judgement of usefulness of the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That particular user requested that their account be deleted. So it was deleted.

As Yannis notes, that's generally how it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I can confirm **practically** Yannis' theoretical answer above. I saw a meta discussion by that user where the user requested a diamond mod to delete their account and was directed by a mod to a standard "please delete my account" request form.

Second, community NEVER gets to decide to delete someone's account. Only moderators (maybe) and/or SE employees can (and probably in extremely small amount of scenarios that are well defined).

Comment: If [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165311/auto-delete-destroy-1-rep-user-when-their-post-is-deleted-as-spam) gets enough support, the community will be able to destroy spam accounts without waiting for the mods to intervene.

Comment: @YannisRizos - I guess I was lucky, I think I only saw ONE instance of actual spam on SE in my many years of active participation on several sites, SO included.

Comment: You're lucky, I destroy spam accounts at least once per week on ProgSE.

Comment: @YannisRizos - you're a mod, you probably get flagged about them :)

Comment: Well, yes, most of the times I discover spam posts from flags, but the users flagging them aren't mods. There's one automated flag that sometimes catches spam answers, but most of the times it's user flags.

Comment: @YannisRizos - May be me mostly hanging out on [Perl] tag helps avoid spam :)